# Toolbar submenu with groups just like in NavigationView

Tags: java, c#, android, xml, xamarin.android

I want to show toolbar submenu after click on icon located on toolbar and after that show submenu looking just like in the image below:

[image]

I should make PopupMenu or PopupWindow? When i tried add dividers to groups they was added after each item. I am not interested in that solution. 
Do you have example with code to make this? For now I only have menu code in XML.

Comment: "For now I only have menu code in XML." . Paste it here

Comment: https://pastebin.com/BrSMjwZD please

Comment: After a day's research, `actionLayout` of menu item doesn't work by my side and I can't figure out why, according to Google's document, it should work for this scenario. But since it doesn't show the layout at all, I think we need to choose `PopupWindow` with self designed layout here.